# Pagination with "withExclusiveStartKey" on a Global Secondary Index

Tags: pagination, amazon-dynamodb

I have DynamoDB table called "product" with a Global Secondary Index on "userId".Primary Key is on "id".
I am trying to implement Querying with pagination using "withExclusiveStartKey"  on "userID" GSI.
However, I get following exception when I pass a valid lastId:

> *Exclusive Start Key must have same size as table's key schema
>   (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code:
>   ValidationException; Request ID:
>   822db97e-04a3-4c36-8c72-6008e2693679)*

What am I doing wrong here ?

```
public QueryResultPage<Product>  findPaged(String userId,int limit,String lastId) {
        DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(dynamoDb);       
        Map<String, AttributeValue> vals = new HashMap<>();
        vals.put(":valUserId", new AttributeValue().withS(userId));
                DynamoDBQueryExpression<Product> queryExp = new         DynamoDBQueryExpression<Product>()
                .withKeyConditionExpression("userId = :valUserId")
                .withIndexName(ModelConsts.TBL_PRODUCT_GSI_USERID)
                .withExpressionAttributeValues(vals)
                .withScanIndexForward(false)
                .withConsistentRead(false)
                .withLimit(limit);  
           if (lastId != null) {//paging
            Map<String, AttributeValue> exclusiveStartKey = new HashMap<String, AttributeValue>();
                    exclusiveStartKey.put("id", new AttributeValue().withS(lastId));
               queryExp = queryExp.withExclusiveStartKey(exclusiveStartKey);
        }   
        QueryResultPage<Product> result = mapper.queryPage(Product.class, queryExp);
        return result;      
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All the key values of the original table of GSI should be set as start key. If the table has partition key and sort key, then both the key values should be set as start key values.

In the below example:-

1) The **`videos`** table has `videoid` as partition key and `category` as sort key

2) The GSI is defined with `category` as partition key and `videoid` as sort key

The below code queries the GSI by `category` value with start key set (i.e. both partition and sort key).

I can reproduce your error when I don't populate the partition or sort key.

**Sample code:-**

```
public QueryResultPage<VideoDynamoMappingAdapter> findVideosByCategoryUsingGSIAndMapperWithStartKey(
        String category) {
    DynamoDBMapper dynamoDBMapper = new DynamoDBMapper(dynamoDBClient);
    QueryResultPage<VideoDynamoMappingAdapter> queryResult = null;
    Map<String, AttributeValue> vals = new HashMap<>();
    vals.put(":val1", new AttributeValue().withS(category));
    DynamoDBQueryExpression<VideoDynamoMappingAdapter> queryExp = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<VideoDynamoMappingAdapter>()
            .withKeyConditionExpression("category = :val1").withIndexName("VideoCategoryGsi")
            .withExpressionAttributeValues(vals).withScanIndexForward(false).withConsistentRead(false).withLimit(1);

    Map<String, AttributeValue> startKey = new HashMap<>();

    startKey.put("videoid", new AttributeValue().withS("2"));
    startKey.put("category", new AttributeValue().withS("Thriller"));

    queryExp.setExclusiveStartKey(startKey);

    queryResult = dynamoDBMapper.queryPage(VideoDynamoMappingAdapter.class, queryExp);

    System.out.println("Result size ===>" + queryResult.getResults().size());
    System.out.println("Last evaluated key ===>" + queryResult.getLastEvaluatedKey());

    for (VideoDynamoMappingAdapter videoDynamoMappingAdapter : queryResult.getResults()) {
        System.out.println("Video data ===>" + videoDynamoMappingAdapter.toString());
    }

    return queryResult;

}
```

Answer (score 34):

I'm writing this answer for those of you, who try to construct the `exclusiveStartKey` *manually*, for a GSI query.  It appears that the exclusive start key is made up of 3 components:

- GSI hash key,
- GSI range key **and**
- the table key

This doesn't seem to be documented anywhere as you are supposed to just use the returned `lastEvaluatedKey` by calling:

```
setLastEvaluatedKey(queryResult.getLastEvaluatedKey());
```

The accepted answer is correct but it leaves the reader with the impression that there are only 2 components to the key, which didn't help in my case.
The solution described here was first mentioned in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/stevearc/flywheel/issues/34#issuecomment-165520416).

Here's how the above is implemented using the AWS Java SDK v2:

```java
QueryRequest.Builder queryBuilder = QueryRequest.builder();
Map<String, AttributeValue> startKey = new HashMap<>(3);
// HASH/PARTITION KEY
startKey.put("gsiHashKeyAttribute", AttributeValue.builder().s(gsiHashKey).build());
// RANGE/SORT KEY
startKey.put("gsiRangeKeyAttribute", AttributeValue.builder().s(gsiRangeKey).build());
// TABLE PRIMARY KEY
startKey.put("tablePrimaryKeyAttribute", AttributeValue.builder().s(tablePrimaryKey).build());
queryBuilder.exclusiveStartKey(startKey);
```

Comment: Then the `QuerySpec.withExclusiveStartKey` signature is misleading because only one of the overloaded will ever work. It's the one accepting the `KeyAttribute`s

Comment: what is the default page size of QueryResultPage?

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thanks. The fact that you need to include the original table primary (partition key) is not documented ANYWHERE.

Answer (score 5):

When considering indexes last evaluated key consist of two things.

1. table keys
2. index keys

you can simply Sysout last evaluated key (EvaluatedKeyMap) from QueryResultPagelast and get the pattern.

in your case, when you are creating exclusiveStartKey add last evaluated "userId" too.
exclusiveStartKey.put("userId", last evaluated user id attibute value);

ex.

```
exclusiveStartKey.put("id", new AttributeValue().withS(lastUserId));
```