# DynamoDB sort and pagination

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to get data from a dynamoDB table sorted but also I want pagination because there are many many rows. This is my query params, `control_id` is GSI with timestamp as sortkey and `id` is primary key. I think what I need is to use both indexes in same query because right now this is what I get `ValidationException: The provided starting key is invalid` and if I remove `ExclusiveStartKey` it works.

```
params = {
 TableName: tableName,
 IndexName: 'control_id',
 KeyConditionExpression: 'control_id = :ci',
 ExpressionAttributeValues: {
  ':ci': 1
 },
 ScanIndexForward: false,
 Limit: 250,
 ExclusiveStartKey: {
  'id': lastKey
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you you have both a partition key and sort key as your primary key, you need to supply both to the ExclusiveStartKey.  Dynamo gives you two options when building a primary key, a partition key, or a composite key (made up of the partition key and sort key).  When using a composite key, always need to provide both the partition key and sort key when referencing a single record in the table

From the docs (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/API_Query_v20111205.html) -

> `ExclusiveStartKey` - Primary key of the item from which to continue an earlier query. An
>   earlier query might provide this value as the LastEvaluatedKey if that
>   query operation was interrupted before completing the query; either
>   because of the result set size or the Limit parameter. The
>   LastEvaluatedKey can be passed back in a new query request to continue
>   the operation from that point.
>
> Type: HashKeyElement, or HashKeyElement and RangeKeyElement for a
>   composite primary key.

here, `HashKeyElement` refers to the partition key, and `RangeKeyElement` refers to the sort key

try

```
ExclusiveStartKey: {
  'id': lastKey
  'created_at': <last key's created_at value>
 }
```

or it might actually be -

```
ExclusiveStartKey: lastkey
```

depending on what you have as `lastKey`, it might already be the composite key

Comment: ```id``` is my primary key, this is how my table looks [link](https://i.ibb.co/DRfrQ1d/img.jpg),
```control_id``` is 1 for every row so i can sort ASC or DESC

Comment: but is `control_id` your sort key?

Comment: from reading above, you say your timestamp is the sort key? If thats the case, your primary key is made up of both `id` an your timestamp, and therefore you need to provide both of those

Comment: No, ```control_id``` is secondary index and ```created_at``` is sort key for ```control_id```, primary key ```id``` has no sort key

Comment: so your primary key for the `control_id` index is a composite key, made of `id` as partition key and `created_at` as sort key, therefore you need to provide both to `ExclusiveStartKey`.  See edit above

Comment: i have something like this now, but still have same error
`params = {
  TableName: tableName,
  IndexName: 'control_id',
  KeyConditionExpression: 'control_id = :ci',
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ':ci': 1
  },
  ScanIndexForward: false,
  Limit: 250,
  ExclusiveStartKey: {
    'id': lastKeyId,
    'created_at': lastKeyCreatedAt
  }
}`

Comment: did you try `ExclusiveStartKey: lastkey` assuming `lastKey` is the key as it returned from the previous query?

Comment: I tried and still not working, i send lastKey in my app, i receive first 250 elements sorted then i press load more button to get next 250 elements and throws error.

Comment: maybe worth looking at the answers in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40988397/dynamodb-pagination-with-withexclusivestartkey-on-a-global-secondary-index looks like there is some stuff around table keys vs index keys